# Removal of Duplicate Urls in list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is a piece of code for acquiring URLS

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for i in range(7):
    r = requests.get(("http://www.yellowpages.com/atlanta-ga/tae-kwon-do?page={}").format(i))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content , "html.parser")
    for link in soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile('/atlanta-ga/mip/')):
        if 'yp-rating' not in link.get('href'):
           if 'geo_location' not in link.get('href'):
              link = (link.get('href'))
              i = set(link)
              for link in i:
                links = (("http://www.yellowpages.com{}").format(link))
                print(links)
```

Have tried many variations and all not getting rid of duplicates.

Here was the original that will give the full list of urls

```
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for i in range(7):
   r = requests.get(("http://www.yellowpages.com/atlanta-ga/tae-kwon-do?page={}").format(i))
   soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content , "html.parser")
   for link in soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile('/atlanta-ga/mip/')):
      if 'yp-rating' not in link.get('href'):
        if 'geo_location' not in link.get('href'):
            link = (link.get('href'))
            links = (("http://www.yellowpages.com{}").format(link))
            print(links)
```

Please correct me on how to remove the list of duplicates here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `set` too early. Create a unique set of links before you enter the first `for` loop:

```
allLinks = set()
for i in range(7):
    ...
```

Then instead of `print(link)` at each iteration, just add `link` to that set; this ensures that it is unique. Or if you want to print it right away, do something like this instead of the `print(link)`

```
if link not in allLinks:
    print(link)
allLinks.add(link)
```